# how to use values of a pandas DataFrame as numpy array index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataFrame like this.

[image]

The X, Y, Z are they (x,y,z) coordinates that represent a point inside a cube of side-length 255.

I want to create a numpy array/dataFrame from this, whose index will be the (x,y,z) coordinates and value is the intensity.

the output should be

```
data[133,55,250] = 8
data[133,61,254] = 21
...
```

I tried something like this

```
data = np.zeros((255,255,255), dtype=np.int)
index = np.array((temp['X'], temp['Y'], temp['Z']))
```

but returned index is a (3,15) array.

I want a index where

```
data[index] = intensity
```

will give me my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
index = np.array((temp['X'], temp['Y'], temp['Z']))
```

you could use [integer array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to perform the assignment:

```
data = np.zeros((256, 256, 256), dtype=np.int)
data[temp['X'], temp['Y'], temp['Z']] = temp['intensity']
```

Comment: Are you using `data[temp['X'], temp['Y'], temp['Z']] = temp['intensity']`? My first answer was incorrect.

Comment: if I do like that, I get this error

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-aec532c66c2e> in <module>()
      1 data = np.zeros((255,255,255), dtype=np.int)
----> 2 data[temp['X'], temp['Y'], temp['Z']] = temp['Intensity']

IndexError: index 255 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 255

Comment: That means you have a value of 255 in `temp[['X','Y','Z']]`, but `data = np.zeros((255,255,255))` is only indexable up to 254 since Python uses 0-based indexing. You can fix it by defining `data = np.zeros((256,256,256))`.